# text field need to long press to get touch down action

Tags: iphone

initially i crate 2 textfields in main view.

And i write IBAction to them and give touch down in interface builder.

But unfortunately  i need to place scroll view in view and place these two text fields on scrollview.

in the IBAction i am calling action sheet. before adding scroll view it works fine but after adding scroll view need to long press other wise keypad will raise instead of Action sheet

what the wrong can any one pls help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to forward the touch the the scroll view? Not sure if it is but just an idea?

Comment: ya it worked but need to long press,if i just press it keypad will raise up

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this `UITextFieldDelegate` method
This will not raise the keypad

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  return NO;
}
```

Do let me know if ths works

Comment: NO change,it takes long press